# Can I compare my success rate on Careers to the average?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs, metrics

I really like the metrics at the bottom of my [job search home page on Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv). It'd be really nifty if I could compare to some site-wide averages so I know when/if I need to spend some time polishing my CV.

Comment: Really? Planned? That's awesome! I'm actually a little surprised, because giving this information to users means you also give it to employers, which means you show your hand a bit about the quality of your system. I guess the goal is to use that as proof that the quality is high. :)

Answer (score 6):

There are a few things that would be interesting (if they were anonymous):

- Success rate for members
- Percentage of members selected with 1-4 years of experience
- Percentage of members that have a Computer Science Degree (as opposed to a lighter degree like 'Computer Information Systems)
- Average length of CV
- length that has the highest rate of getting a job (average)
- Number of times CV appears in a search (but not selected for interview)

Comment: As opposed to a 'Creative Literature' degree, too.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't planned right now.  If you'd like to see it, go ahead and vote it up.  You *can* see the completeness score which tells you a bunch of things you should add to your profile.